# Parsing a remote csv line by line ruby

Tags: ruby, parsing, csv

I've got a remote CSV that updates every few hours, it has 1m+ rows and I'm trying to work out if I can download the file line by line and parse it (I'm only interested in the first 500,000 lines) rather than have to download the whole file then process it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like this...

```
require 'csv'
require 'open-uri'

def read(url)
  open(url) do |f|
    f.each_line do |l|
      CSV.parse(l) do |row|
        p [row] 
      end
    end 
  end
end
```